# MVC5 + EF + UOW + Services Layer where to call SaveChanges() and avoid multiple trips to DB?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

I'm building a web application using: **MVC5** and **EF Code First** with **Repository** and **Unit of Work** Patterns. Till now I have 3 layers:

- "Data Layer" which contains the repositories, UOW.
- "Services Layer" which has refrence to UOW to implement bussiness logic and bussiness validation.
- "Web Layer" which is reponsible for displaying the data through communicating with the services layer.

My Domain/Business Objects are separated in another project. So basically I'm following John Papa [CodeCamper](https://github.com/johnpapa/CodeCamper) structure except adding the "Services Layer".

**Data/Contracts/IRepository.cs**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(int id);
}
```

**Data/Contracts/IUnitOfWork.cs**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    // Save pending changes to the data store.
    void Commit();

    // Repositories
    IRepository<Event> Events { get; }
    IRepository<Candidate> Candidates { get; }
}
```

**Data/EFRepository.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// The EF-dependent, generic repository for data access
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of entity for this Repository.</typeparam>
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public EFRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        //return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(PredicateBuilder.GetByIdPredicate<T>(id));
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id);
        if (entity == null) return; // not found; assume already deleted.
        Delete(entity);
    }
}
```

**Data/UnitOfWork.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// The "Unit of Work"
///     1) decouples the repos from the controllers
///     2) decouples the DbContext and EF from the controllers
///     3) manages the UoW
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class implements the "Unit of Work" pattern in which
/// the "UoW" serves as a facade for querying and saving to the database.
/// Querying is delegated to "repositories".
/// Each repository serves as a container dedicated to a particular
/// root entity type such as a <see cref="Url"/>.
/// A repository typically exposes "Get" methods for querying and
/// will offer add, update, and delete methods if those features are supported.
/// The repositories rely on their parent UoW to provide the interface to the
/// data layer (which is the EF DbContext in this example).
/// </remarks>
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public UnitOfWork(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
        CreateDbContext();

        repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;       
    }

    // Repositories
    public IRepository<Student> Students { get { return GetStandardRepo<Event>(); } }
    public IRepository<Course> Courses { get { return GetStandardRepo<Course>(); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save pending changes to the database
    /// </summary>
    public void Commit()
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Committed");
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected void CreateDbContext()
    {
        DbContext = new UnicornsContext();

        // Do NOT enable proxied entities, else serialization fails
        DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        // Load navigation properties explicitly (avoid serialization trouble)
        DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        // Because Web API will perform validation, I don't need/want EF to do so
        DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    protected IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider { get; set; }

    private IRepository<T> GetStandardRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>();
    }
    private T GetRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepository<T>();
    }

    private UnicornsContext DbContext { get; set; }

    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (DbContext != null)
            {
                DbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and then finally use Ninject to resolve dependency:

```
kernel.Bind<RepositoryFactories>().To<RepositoryFactories>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IRepositoryProvider>().To<RepositoryProvider>();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
```

Where should I call `UOW.Commit()` so that I can reuse implemented logic of a specific service in other services instead of re-writing it again?

1. Does the controller should be resposible for commiting changes?
2. Or should the service itself commit the changes?

As far I have read on Stack Overflow, **option(1)** is simpler but violates Single Responsibility Principle or what would be the case if I want to integrate with mobile/desktop applications.

**Option(2):** here I ***MUST*** call commit in every service function call and hence I won't be able to reuse function as this may cause multiple trips to DB.

Comment: FYI, what you have done does *NOT* decouple EF from your Web layer... or controllers.  Your Repositories return IQueryable's, which are going to be tightly coupled to Entity Framework regardless.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch can you explain more your point or what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

In my Project, I call Save() in the controller, because I want to reuse my methods as much as possible and "gluing" multiple methods together is difficult when they are calling Save() themselves. 
Worse, if there are errors on the contorller level, you might want to avoid calling save(), e.g. some method creates a bunch of small objects, which are used in a master-object which has to be commited. Committing both at the same time seems to be better than a hardocded commit in the createSMallObject() and createMasterObject(), in case something happens in between.

Comment: what if i want to use my services layer in a mobile application through API or use it in a desktop application? i have no controller here

Comment: Adding a save() method, which must be explicitly called? That mirrors the ef design after all...